# Create protocol var that conforms to another protocol

Tags: ios, swift, animation, protocols

I have my Swift project where I want to create an animator. I'll use this animator object in all my view controller creating a specific object for every one of them. The actual animator object must conform to the `Animator` protocol. See the example :

This is the `Animator` protocol :

```
protocol Animator {

    associatedtype ViewControllerGeneric
    var controller: ViewControllerGeneric { get }

    /// Init the animator
    ///
    /// - Parameter controller: The UIViewController to bind to the animator
    init(withController controller: ViewControllerGeneric)
}
```

This is an actual animator object :

```
class SolutionAnimator: Animator {

    private (set) var controller: SolutionsViewController

    required init(withController controller: SolutionsViewController) {

        self.controller = controller
    }
}
```

Here everything is fine. Then, I want that all my `UIViewController`s subclasses adhere to my other protocol `UIViewControllerAnimator`, that is this :

```
protocol UIViewControllerAnimator {

    associatedtype AnimatorObject: Animator
    var animator: AnimatorObject { get set }
}
```

Here I want to have a var named `animator` that is of a generic type `AnimatorObject` that have to conform to `Animator` protocol.

When I write everything in MyViewController, like this :

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerAnimator {

    var animator: SolutionAnimator!
}
```

Xcode tells me that `MyViewController` doesn't conform to protocol `UIViewControllerAnimator`.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyViewController` doesn't conform to `UIViewControllerAnimator`. Your protocol requires:

```
associatedtype AnimatorObject: Animator
var animator: AnimatorObject { get set }
```

And your class provides:

```
var animator: SolutionAnimator!
```

But `SolutionAnimator!` doesn't conform to `Animator`. `SolutionAnimator` does. Remove the `!`.

If you have some technical reason that you cannot remove the `!` (for instance, if this is being instantiated from a storyboard, that can be unworkable), then you just need to hide the `!` so that you correctly conform to the protocol:

```
private var _animator: SolutionAnimator!
var animator: SolutionAnimator {
    get { return _animator }
    set { _animator = newValue }
}
```